# Conditionally Read Messages From RabbitMQ With Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring Boot app that sits between an upstream RabbitMQ broker and a downstream REST service. It reads messages from a queue in the upstream broker and posts data from the message to the downstream REST service

For reading the messages I'm using the `@RabbitListener` annotation

I have a scheduled check for health of the REST service. If it is not available, I would like to stop reading messages from the RabbitMQ queue. I've a feeling it might require customising the RabbitListenerContainer, but I'm not sure if this is correct or where to start

Any help on configuring message consumption only while a condition is met would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to the container from the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry`  infrastructure bean (give the listener(s) an `id`).

You can then stop/start the container(s) as needed.